# Accessing specific portions/values in a Column

Tags: postgresql

Experts,

I have this table in PG - I need to convert my output to the green part. [image]

So in short extract certain parts and make them a different column. I can easily do this in Python but kind of stuck on Postgres.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a simple string operation:

```
select manufacturer,
       address,
       contact, 
       left(contact::text, 3) as result_1, 
       right(contact::text, 3) as result_2
from the_table;
```